# check bitmap for an image validation c#

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmapimage

I am checking four corners of a document to check if there will be an image. How can i possibly do this with my following code. I get all four corners of a document but i would like to get which corner has an image(qr code) and then pass in that corner to the method after.

**Code:**

```
using (var fullImg = new Bitmap(workGif))
                {

                    Bitmap result = fullImg;
                    //top-left
                    var bandImg1 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, result.Width/2, result.Height/2), fullImg.PixelFormat);

                    //top-right
                    var bandImg2 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(result.Width / 2, 0, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                    //bottom-left
                    var bandImg3 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                    //bottom-right
                    var bandImg4 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);

                    Bitmap[] corners = new Bitmap[] { bandImg1, bandImg2, bandImg3, bandImg4 };
                    string QRinfo = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < corners.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        string tempQRinfo = Process(corners[i]);
                        if (tempQRinfo == null)
                        {
                            QRinfo = tempQRinfo;
                            switch (i)
                            {
                                case 0: break; //upper left
                                case 1: fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone); break;
                                case 2: fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone); break;
                                case 3: fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone); break;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

**Process method**

```
public string Process(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var reader = new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader();

        try
        {
            LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
            return reader.decode(binBitmap).Text;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could be interrested by AForge: it's an open source library that contains image processing components - http://code.google.com/p/aforge/

Comment: @Laurent great to know and have on hand - thanks. But i was looking maybe for a work around solution within the code. Checking if the clone i made has an image or not.

Comment: I think this was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289616/com-google-zxing-binarybitmap-error-with-handling-bitmap-image